# Are questions about how to design an implementation of certain parts of a game appropriate?

Tags: discussion, questions

When I'm stuck on some aspect in one of the many dead-end game projects I start, can I ask for advice about how to design it here?

If I have an idea about how I want something to work functionally, but am not sure of the best approach to implementing it, would a question about that be appropriate?

It's definitely about game development, so is on-topic. It is somewhat subjective, but I don't think to the extent that would be a problem.

I'm more concerned that it might be considered something that would lead to extensive discussion, and be more appropriate for some other forum.

What are peoples thoughts, or does anyone have any guidelines about how to ask this sort of question such that it would fit well with this site?

**Edit:**

I've gone ahead and posted my question:

[How can I implement a command system for a point-and-click style adventure game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/601/how-can-i-implement-a-command-system-for-a-point-and-click-style-adventure-game)

Any suggestions on whether that is a good fit, or how it should be asked differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conceptually it seems like an excellent fit for this site. A bit of subjectivity is fine, the only real problem, as you say, would be if it devolved too much into a discussion*. That being said, I think that if you choose the wording of your question carefully to keep it focused on one specific issue and not too vague, so that someone can clearly/directly answer it, you should be fine (you may find that it works better if you break your broader issue down into a series of simpler, answerable parts).

I'd suggest posting an example question or two while we're in beta to see how it goes...

<sub>* possibly a good opportunity for the coming "third place" chat.</sub>

Comment: Agreed. As long as it's kept academic it should be allright.

Answer (score 6):

We are going to have to deal with a little bit of that subjectivity here. Different people will have different ideals about how a to execute a concept, but in general I see no reason why it shouldn't be.